# Hidding and showing form elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to hide some form elements and only show them when I need them.

The problem with my code is that hidden elements still consume space.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Example code:

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/2YdbH/6/)

Check element #choice. It is hidden but it still takes space in the website.

Comment: It doesnt look to be consuming space to me... it seems you might have overlooked the `<br/>` tag in your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they don't take place, but the surrounding

```
<br>
```

do...

either wrap in div

```
<div class="initiallyhidden">
<br/>    
<select>.....</select>
<br/>
</div>
```

and hide that, or leave our br and style the spacing

Answer (score 2):

The `<br/>` are messing this up. Your jsfiddle isn't proving that the elements still take up space. Look at how I modified it:

http://jsfiddle.net/2YdbH/12/

Select type 3 to show everything, select type 1 to hide everything, and then select type 4 to show only the text area. Notice how the textarea is flush up against the type dropdown. The choice selector doesn't take up space.

When you hide the choice selector, the `<br/>`'s are still there in the html, so you're seeing two returns.

Answer (score 1):

The space you see is caused by your `<br/>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

hide n show `br` tags:

```
$("br").hide()
```